# Less tedious way to call values from the command line?

Tags: c

I currently have:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   char* array = argv[1];
   char* test = argv[2];
   char*p;
   char*q;
   long check;
   long checker;

   check = strtol(array, &p, 3);
   checker = strtol(test, &q, 3);
   printf("Check: %ld\n", check);
}
```

What would be faster/ more efficient way of calling the values from the command line without having to create a new variable (p,q,check,checker) every time a new value is called? ie. ./program 1 2 3

Also, why do values such as -9 in "./program -9 2 3" return 0?

Comment: You must add more. What will be the purpose of p, q, check,checker??

Comment: Why do you use the `%ld` formatting directive with `test`, an object of type `char*`? This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @YasirMajeed: They're just there to transition the numbers that are input into the argument (First day of learning C I'm not sure if this is what you were asking for

Comment: @BLUEPIXY@Fuzxxl my mistake , modified the code

Comment: then the best solution for you to use functions like atoi and atol. These functions convert string to int and to long respectively. Instead of first copying them to char*, directly convert argv[i] as atol(argv[index])

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply. I'm a beginner, I've been reading up on atol but people are saying strtol is much superior because atoi only have one retur n value?

Comment: You might like to RTFM here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html especially about the 3rd parameter to `strtol()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does `-9` fail? Because you specify a `ternary` input for `strtol()` which only uses the digits `0..2`.

It would be simpler to do it in a loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    long check = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        check = strtol(argv[i], NULL, 3);
        printf("arg %d = %ld\n", i, check);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program input/output using your values, and a fourth to show the ternary to decimal conversion

```
F:\WORK\MYTOOLS\CTEST>test -9 2 3 111
arg 1 = 0
arg 2 = 2
arg 3 = 0
arg 4 = 13
```

Did you pass `3` to `strtol()` because you thought you were passing the 3 inputs from the command line? If you didn't really mean the input to be in `ternary`, this revision should do what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    long check = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        check = atol(argv[i]);
        printf("arg %d = %ld\n", i, check);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And now it works in decimal

```
F:\WORK\MYTOOLS\CTEST>test -9 2 3 111
arg 1 = -9
arg 2 = 2
arg 3 = 3
arg 4 = 111
```

Comment: sorry I'm very new what exactly is a ternary input for strtol? I passed 3 because I thought that was supposed to indicate "triple digit"
EDIT: Just saw the edit you have made that is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Ternary is the number base used by the input string. Like, binary, ternary, octal, decimal, hexadecimal. If you had put a `10` instead of the `3` that would work. But `strtol()` only converts *one* number.